# How do I bind actions to links in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a website which has a thumbnail navigation on it's about us page, and for each person you click their profile is displayed inside the same box. Then by clicking "close" at the bottom of the profile it takes you back to the thumbnails.

So far I have the following divs...

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="thumbnails"></div>
    <div id="profile-1"></div>
    <div id="profile-2"></div>
    <div id="profile-3"></div>
    <div id="profile-4"></div>

<div>
```

Inside the div named "people" I have...

```
<ul>
    <li class="thumbnail-1"><a href="#">Profile 1</a></li>
    <li class="thumbnail-2"><a href="#">Profile 2</a></li>
    <li class="thumbnail-3"><a href="#">Profile 3</a></li>
    <li class="thumbnail-4"><a href="#">Profile 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

My thinking was to position all divs absolutely so they are on top of one another and then hide all profiles on document load.

Then when a thumbnail is clicked bind a display: block and z-index: 100 to the corresponding profile forcing the profile to display on top of the thumbnails.

My question is would this be the best way to do this? What jquery would I need to generate this behavior so that it removes the css properties created when the close button is clicked?

Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: you want when a thumbnail is clicked: which will just be a bullet? or you want when the matching div is clicked?

Comment: Hi. Only after reading what I have wrote have I realised how ambiguous my question sounds. I should have provided a mockup. Thanks for everyones suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Demo](http://jsbin.com/iyefi)

I just realized you wanted the total opposite of what I initially put, but for one: it would be good to name your id of your divs the **exact** name for your anchor tag as text so, and also in order to have a text to click on something must be inside your div:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="thumbnails"></div>//I don't even use this, so if you don't use it for something else you can get rid of this line
    <div id="Profile-1">first one</div>
    <div id="Profile-2">second one</div>
    <div id="Profile-3">third one</div>
    <div id="Profile-4">fourth one</div>
</div>
<ul id="thumbnails">
    <li><a href="#">Profile-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile-3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile-4</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#container').hide(); //hide the links in the list
        $('#thumbnails a').click(function () {  // bind the li's click event
            var id = $(this).text();
            $("#container div").each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr("id") == id) {
                    $(this).show().parent().show();
                }
                else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is along the right lines, but how do I hide the thumbnails after they are clicked. I'd like only one div at a time to show, including thumbnails.

Comment: this shows only one div. you want it to show only the profile link clicked also? but that would hide all the the others making you have to refresh the page in order to select another 'div'

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm after. Then there will be a link inside each profile that will let you go back to the thumbnails div.

Comment: just add these two lines:  $('#thumbnails li a').hide(); $(this).show(); after the 'click' but before the 'each'

Answer (score 5):

Don't do that. Just show/hide them as you need to:

```
$("#thumbnails a").click(function() {
  var id = "profile" + this.id.substring(1);
  $("#container").children().hide();
  $("#" + id).show();
  return false;
});
```

assuming the following, which has slightly changed it:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="thumbnails"></div>
  <div id="profile-1"></div>
  <div id="profile-2"></div>
  <div id="profile-3"></div>
  <div id="profile-4"></div>
<div>
```

and

```
<ul id="thumbnails">
  <li><a id="t-1" href="#">Profile 1</a></li>
  <li><a id="t-2" href="#">Profile 2</a></li>
  <li><a id="t-3" href="#">Profile 3</a></li>
  <li><a id="t-4" href="#">Profile 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

The reason for this is you want to put as little marker HTML in as possible. You could further change this by removing the IDs from the links if you can assume that you can infer the ID from the position within the list. That's just one possible alteration.

The use of IDs seems appropriate when you're marking page elements like container and thumbnails as well. Plus ID lookup is much, much faster than the alternatives.

Comment: Don't forget to 'return false;' at the end otherwise the link will be followed. Granted, it will just follow to 'URLhere#' but that could still be annoying because it will scroll the page to the top. ;)

Comment: With this suggestion I wasn't able to stop the link from being followed even with return false. Did I get the syntax wrong?

Comment: Load it in Firefox and check your errors console for Javascript errors.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try modifying your HTML in the way that the profile and the thumbnail are in the same construct.

```
<ul>
    <li class="person">
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="profile"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You could still use absolute positioning for the div.profile:s, but your javascript would be easier (and without any string manipulation needed) since you only need to find a sibling element.

```
$('div.thumbnail').click(
    $('div.profile').removeClass('visible'); // hide any visible profiles
    $(this).siblings('div.profile').addClass('visible'); // show the adjacent profile
);
```

(The above example assumes that the div.profile.visible css-class is used to show a profile.)